# nginx rewrite for new links structure

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

i just moved my server from *apache* to *nginx*, and my main site from *joomla* to *wordpress* (now it is a lot faster, but it cost me two months of learning nginx, and testing new configs etc.). Only problem that left is with new links structure.

Can somebody help me to rewrite old links to the new one?

**This is mine links structure:**

**OLD**> http://www.example.com/this-is-just-some-text-1234.html

**NEW** > https://www.example.com/this-is-just-some-text-09878

Main text in most cases stays the same, but post-id number is changed, and there is no .html at the end. http > https redirects are in nginx config already.

Answer (score 1):

This can't really be done with nginx alone -- how would nginx have any idea what was the old ID with Joomla, and the new one with WordPress?  It sounds like your transition process wasn't done correctly.

However, if you do have a list of old and corresponding new URLs, you can use the the `map` directive within nginx to supply such list.

```
map $uri $new_uri {
    /this-is-just-some-text-1234.html /this-is-just-some-text-09878;
}

if ($new_uri) {
    return 301 $new_uri;
}
```

References:

- http://nginx.org/r/map
- http://nginx.org/r/if